# Under what circumstances do I have to buy the mega stone for my second starter?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

It is [known](http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/18014/article/pokemon-x-and-y-mega-stones-locations-guide/) that under some circumstances you do not automatically receive the mega stone for your second starter Pokemon (Charmander, Squirtle, Bulbasaur) when you obtain the pokemon from Professor Sycamore. Instead you have to purchase the Mega Stone from the Mega Stone Salesman.

What are the circumstances that trigger this situation?

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly certain you'll *always* get the mega stone for the gen1 starter you picked from Sycamore (with charizadite having version exclusive X and Y variants). But the stones for the two gen1 starters you **didn't** pick are available from the guy in the Stone Emporium.

The phrasing on the website you linked;

> If you didn't get it from him, you will be able to buy it from a man in the Stone Emporium in Lumiose City in the postgame.

May have given you the impression that it's possible to not get the stone for the starter you picked, but it is meant to indicate that the other two stones for the gen1 starter mega evolutions are available elsewhere. Also note that the price of the mega stones in the Stone Emporium goes down the more '[stylish](http://www.serebii.net/xy/lumiosestyle.shtml)' you are after you've beaten the elite 4 (down to a minimum of 10,000).